# not found при установке dnvm

Tags: ubuntu, asp.net-core

Не могу установить dnvm, ссылка выдает:

> 404: Not Found

Данный пример взят из [официальной документации](http://dotnet.today/ru/aspnet5-vnext/getting-started/installing-on-linux.html):

```
$ curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aspnet/Home/dev/dnvminstall.sh | DNX_BRANCH=dev sh && source ~/.dnx/dnvm/dnvm.sh
```

что делать? как установить dnvm на ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

судя по содержимому неработающей ссылки, речь об [этом репозитории](https://github.com/aspnet/Home), в котором данный файл [удалён 11 дней назад](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/commit/6833b6d73ac3e755e7314f4c488c8ec7abdcc67b#diff-d76fba8356454bd8006f3630b4eee15d).

его содержимое до удаления можно получить по [этой ссылке](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aspnet/Home/b77ee2c7d112d3c151d7546c1f8a094b6cb798d6/dnvminstall.sh). но вот стоит ли запускать этот скрипт, я не подскажу. вероятно, причина удаления достаточно серьёзна, и, надеюсь, описана либо в [readme.md репозитория](https://github.com/aspnet/Home), либо по какой-нибудь из ссылок, там перечисленных.